# JSP не отображается png

Tags: java, jsp, include

есть код в JSP:

```
<img src="../icons/directory.png" alt="">
```

Не отображаются картинки png. Указывал разные варианты пути, ни один не сработал. Пробовал `"/icons/directory.png" alt="">"` и без первого слеша. Через url localhost/views/main.jsp видит jsp файлы, открывает их. При попытке открыть какой-нибудь png файл редиректит на основной сервлет. Не понимаю, в чем может быть проблема?

Comment: А jpg отображаются?

Comment: Нет, jpg тоже не отображается

Answer (score 1, accepted):

web.xml должен быть вот таким :

```
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         version="2.4" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">

    <display-name>Spring MVC Application</display-name>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            30
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.gif</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.jpg</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.jpeg</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.png</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.mp4</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <filter>
        <filter-name>characterEncodingFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>encoding</param-name>
            <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>forceEncoding</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>characterEncodingFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
</web-app>
```

это для картинок , иконок и.т.д